# Grammatical analysis of these two sentences

Tags: grammar, verbs, clauses, subjects, objects

> 1. Isn’t Istanbul a good city?

and

> 2. Istanbul is a good city, isn’t it?

In (1) what is the term for how “Isn’t Istanbul” is being used here? At first it looks like its function is to act as the subject, but it looks like an extended noun phrase on second glance acting as pre-modifiers to “a good city”.

From what I can see in (2) “a good city” is the predicative nominative with “Istanbul” acting as subject. The “isn’t it” is a subordinate clause.

Comment: It seems odd to parse “Isn’t Istanbul” as a noun phrase. It also makes #1 ungrammatical. What is your justification for that parsing?

Comment: @Lawrence it’s come unnoticed as odd when spoken in everyday vernacular and it’s not uncommon when compared with other negative interrogatives, “don’t you know English?”. I believe they are called question tags. E.g. You’re John aren’t you? / aren’t you John?

Comment: As for my justification for the parsing of it as a noun phrase is because of its syntax position, I don’t know if it is, I would just like to hear people’s opinion. What part of speech or what the function of “Isn’t Istanbul” in the sentence? I don’t think it’s a finite verb: that would be *Istanbul isn’t a good city* (but that is a statement not a question). So  we have maybe “Isn’t” as a non finite verb acting as subject (some sort of particle/gerund) with the noun Istanbul and NP (a good city) = ext noun phrase. You’re right it would be ungrammatical as there would be no lexical verb; ..

Comment: ... but rules are often broken in spoken language. Q: What did you see? A: A gigantic statue with ancient carvings (= no lexical verb).

Comment: (1) is a negative _Yes/No_ Question. _Isn't_ comes first because of Subject-Auxiliary Inversion. (2) is a Tag Question formed from the affirmative statement version of (1); the tag is negative because the base statement is affirmative.

Comment: @aesking "Isn't Istanbul" isn't a question tag. I'd say it is an incorrect parsing. I'd parse it as "*(Isn't) (Istanbul a good city)?*" If you parsed "Isn't Istanbul" as a noun phrase, replace the purported noun phrase with "X" and you'd have "X a good city?", which isn't grammatical. If X was really a noun phrase, you could argue that "X a good city?" is informal / colloquial, but I don't think you can argue that "Isn't Istanbul" is actually a noun phrase - there's no concept, object, etc that "Isn't Istanbul" refers to.

Comment: @Lawrence sorry I didn’t say “Isn’t Istanbul” was a question tag but rather it contained a question tag. Sorry for misunderstanding; should have made this clear. What is “isn’t” then in relation to the rest of the sentence? What part of speech/phrase/function/is it modifying anything etc. Is there a lexical verb in this question? Also in some grammars just being the subject (either a direct subject or some particle functioning as a subject e.g usually non-finite verbs - gerunds etc.) of the sentence constitutes a NP.

Comment: @JohnLawler but because of subject-auxiliary inversion, is “isn’t” still a finite verb like before inversion: 1) Istanbul isn’t a good city vs. 2) Isn’t Istanbul a good city? To me before and after inversion produces different sentences with different meanings. So because of subject-auxiliary inversion, isn’t the “finite verb” kinda acting like the subject where the subject is in the syntax position of where the auxiliary verb should be...

Comment: *Is* is a verb. It's the same as saying *Are not [aren't] you tired?* In that construction, *are not you* is ***not*** a noun phrase. It's theoretically possible to parse it as a noun phrase—but then, as already said, the sentence would become at least undiiomatic. It would be no different than saying *Istanbul a good city?*

Comment: @Jason Bassford I wouldn’t question *is* being a verb in its finite form but because of the subject and verb inversion and the reverse positions; I’m not sure whether to call *is* a finite verb, perhaps a non-finite. I think inverting the subject and auxiliary positions changes the whole grammar of the sentence and so should the analyses.

Comment: _Is_ is an auxiliary verb. So is _isn't_, since it works exactly like _is_ with regard to Subject-Auxiliary Inversion. _Is he coming?_ and _Isn't he coming?_ both invert. As a general rule, new words formed by contraction or reification fit right into single-word slots, and their fusional source is not held against them.

Comment: @JohnLawler Might you be able to help with [this Q](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/33888/positive-negative-polarity-items-and-interrogatives) here?

Comment: I've never heard of Interrogative Polarity items. Though I suppose they're possible. A lot would depend on the types of question, I suspect.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't suppose Int PI's make much sense, given the lack of polarity sensitivity. Maybe non-declarative-context-items or something?

Comment: Yeah, I view polarity as the same phenomenon as binding; logical operators (modals, negatives, quantifiers) have ranges of polarity (or binding), which are subject to all kinds of constraints. And interact strangely.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is derived as follows:

Istambul is a good city. (Declarative or statement form)
Is Istambul a good city? (Yes/No interrogative)
Yes, Istambul is a good city. (Positive reply/answer)
No, Istambul is not a good city. (Negative answer)
Isn't Istambul a good city? (Negative interrogative) When a question tag is added to it, it goes like "Istambul is a good citym, isn't it?"

This is a single-clause sentence with Istambul as the subject, IS, the verb, and the remaining make a complement phrase.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. You didn’t answer what “isn’t Istanbul” is in the negative interrogative.